Does trace.json generated with flag --disabled-by-default-skia contain all SKIA commands used by the browser?
While loading a page in Chromium, I am generating trace.json with the flag --disabled-by-default-skia
I see many SKIA commands logged in the file in this category like so
{"args":{},"cat":"disabled-by-default-skia","name":"void __cdecl SkCanvas::drawRect(const SkRect &, const SkPaint &)","ph":"I","pid":26192,"s":"t","tid":26400,"ts":95856534713}

My purpose is to extract these commands and replay them on another browser using CanvasKit.
What I don't understand is - whether this file covers all the SKIA commands?
Tried generating trace.json for a website being loaded in chromium with the flag --disabled-by-default-skia
Expecting it to contain all the SKIA commands used.
